# Keep track of UITableViewCell dynamics

Tags: ios

I'm implementing a download system and I have this table view with elements from Core Data.

I would like the user to press a download button on a cell and the system will start begin downloading the related file.

I have my download library that can communicate and report progress through delegate methods, my problem is that I don't know how to relate/properly redisplay/update a progress view in reusable cells.

The download library works with NSURLs, I can subclass NSURL and append a property protocol representing my core data instance, but even then what's the best way to keep the UI updated cell by cell?

Should I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` every time the delegate receives an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, this is a tricky problem. As you have noticed, the cell objects are being reused as the table is scrolled and there is no guarantee the the same cell object will continue to reference the same index path of your table.

I would suggest taking a look at `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` It is called on the table view delegate right before a cell is about to be displayed. This would be a good place to set this cell as the correct delegate within your downloading library.

As to your second question, no, do not call `[self.tableView reloadData]` on each event. That would be a performance crushing decision. :)

Comment: The advice is good; I though about `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` but setting the download library delegate here on a cell it means that it will receive all download events, as the library cannot have more then one delegate. So the idea was to setup the table controller as the delegate of the download library, implement the methods and perform UI tasks based on the delegate method (progress for example).

Comment: My problem now is to catch up the correct cell from the delegate method (which most likely doesn't know anything about cells, only NSURLs at most) by looking at an object with perhaps attached a property that I will use to look up the Core Data collection. After I have the Core Data record find the cell (?), check if it is visible (won't work), etc.

Comment: I'm not sure how others are doing it, in the Music app you can see a download icon per cell to download the file, when it begins downloading the progress view (I still have to understand if it's a button or an accessoryView) updates itself and is able to being redrawn at the same point where it was left off the screen.